# Is it possible to fix an image to a webpage with a fluid layout?

Tags: html, css

I am constructing a website based off of the [Fluid 960 GS System](http://www.designinfluences.com/fluid960gs/16/). I want to overlay an image in the header so that it stays put relative to the header image without disrupting the header itself. If I use the following CSS, I get halfway there:

```
.imgFloat {
    position:absolute;
    left:400px;
    top:-2px;
    z-index:1;  
}

<div class="grid_16">
    <h1 id="branding">
        <a href=""><img src="img/logo.png" /></a>
        <img src="img/float.png" class="imgFloat" />
    </h1>
</div>
```

The only "issue" (not really since the CSS is doing what it is supposed to) with this code is that the image stays put rather than being staying x pixels away from the header image like I want.

If I change the position to relative, it breaks the size of the header and thus the layout of the header itself, but it will position the image like I want.

Is there a happy medium CSS "trick" that I can apply to achieve this result?

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to make sure that the absolute positioned element is inside the element you want it to be relative to. Then just add `position: relative` to that element and it should work.

So:

```
tag(position:relative)
  ag(position:absolute; left:2px)
```

Should work

I'm just guessing here since the code you're showing is not detailed enough ;)

**Update**:

```
#branding {position:relative}

.imgFloat {
    position:absolute;
    left:400px;
    top:-2px;
    z-index:1;  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have edited the question to show the code where the image is.

Comment: Updated with code, that should do the trick. Please note that #branding should have a size.

Answer (score 0):

set `position: relative` on the header element that wraps the .imgFloat element that should lock an absolutely positioned element to the wrapper.

Also you'll need to change your positions since the left will be relative to the 0,0 coordinate of the wrapper element.